Is my extented LUKS partition encrypted?
I added a second NVME on my computer and extended my encrypted LVM volume. I used the following commands to extend it :
sudo pvcreate /dev/nvme0n1            << New disk
sudo vgextend castel-vg /dev/nvme0n1
sudo lvm lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/castel-vg/root
sudo resize2fs -p /dev/mapper/castel--vg-root

The partition is well extended and all works fine, but now if I look the lsblk result :
lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
nvme1n1                   259:0    0  3.6T  0 disk  
├─nvme1n1p1               259:1    0  512M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─nvme1n1p2               259:2    0  488M  0 part  /boot
└─nvme1n1p3               259:3    0  3.6T  0 part  
  └─nvme0n1p3_crypt       254:0    0  3.6T  0 crypt 
    ├─castel--vg-root     254:1    0  7.3T  0 lvm   /
    └─castel--vg-swap_1   254:2    0  976M  0 lvm   [SWAP]
nvme0n1                   259:4    0  3.6T  0 disk  
└─castel--vg-root         254:1    0  7.3T  0 lvm   /

The last two lines are giving me a doubt that the partition castel--vg-root on the drive nvme0n1 isn't using the LUKS encryption layer. Is there any way to confirm or not that the extended partition is well encrypted ?
Update:

While I was trying to draw this, to help clarify my question (the ?? part), I notice that this is also not clear to me where the crypt/LUKS is. Is nvme0n1p3_crypt a Partition or a VolumeGroup ?

Yes, while nvme0n1p3 is an encrypted volume (see TYPE column), nvme0n1 is not encrypted.
Apart from encryption, it's ridiculous to have a root volume of 7 TB. It's a sign of unwise space management.

@NikitaKipriyanov thanks for the answer. If I agree with the unwise space management, I'm not sure to understand the answer. I agree that nvme0n1 is not encrypted, but it's still not clear to me if the content of the root volume (even included in the _crypt LUKS partition) is really encrypted on nvme0n1 or if the encrypted part only concerns the nvme1n1p3 partition

No it isn't. Your volume group is currently build on top of two physical volumes (PVs) and only one of these is currently using LUKS for encryption (nvme0n1p3_crypt) and the second one is just a plain disk without any encryption configured (nvme0n1). This means the data on your root logical volume is only partially encrypted -- data that LVM will write on your first PV will be encrypted, data written on the second PV won't (because you resized your root LV it is now using space on both PVs).
To fix this I'd recommend starting over (assuming that you didn't fill the new space on your root LV yet) -- shrink back the root logical volume (fortunately it is ext filesystem so it can be shrinked), remove the second PV from your VG and this time before readding it create LUKS on it first (it is possible to add LUKS to an existing device, but LUKS reencryption can be a bit complicated and in this case it's probably easier to just start over).
And after that repeat your previous steps but before running pvcreate run:

cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/nvme0n1
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1 nvme0n1_crypt
pvcreate /dev/mapper/nvme0n1_crypt

then use cryptsetup luksDump /dev/nvme0n1 to get UUID of the LUKS device and add it to your /etc/crypttab to make sure it is unlocked during boot. Make sure to regenerate your initramfs using dracut -fv (on RHEL/Fedora systems, it's different on different distributions).
